# Groovy / grails how to determine a data type?

Tags: groovy, types

What is the best way to determine the data type in groovy?

I'd like to format the output differently if it's a date, etc.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

To determine the class of an object simply call:

```
someObject.getClass()
```

You can abbreviate this to `someObject.class` in most cases. However, if you use this on a `Map` it will try to retrieve the value with key 'class'. Because of this, I always use `getClass()` even though it's a little longer.

If you want to check if an object implements a particular interface or extends a particular class (e.g. Date) use:

```
(somObject instanceof Date)
```

or to check if the class of an object is *exactly* a particular class (not a subclass of it), use:

```
(somObject.getClass() == Date)
```

Comment: `instanceof` is great for filtering based on interface.

Comment: At least in the latest Groovy (2.3.7), we can also write someObject.class

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE that works in most cases, but not in all, e.g. a `Map` instance

Comment: You're right : we get null in this case. Apologizing for the mistake.

Comment: Then what is this?

`def test = {}

println test.getClass()`


class Script1$_run_closure1

??

Comment: @Petrunov every closure is an anonymous subclass of `groovy.lang.Closure`. The name of the class is generated by the compiler, so`"Script1$_run_closure1"` is the name generated for your specific closure. This is pretty much the same for Java anonymous classes.

Answer (score 35):

Simple groovy way to check object type:

```
somObject in Date
```

Can be applied also to interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add another option to Dónal's answer, you can also still use the good old `java.lang.Object.getClass()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Membership Operator isCase() which is another groovy way:

```
assert Date.isCase(new Date())
```

Answer (score -21):

`somObject instanceof Date`

should be

`somObject instanceOf Date`

Comment: This is not correct. `instanceof` should all be in lower-case.