# Determine return type of Groovy expression

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have some string with Groovy expression. I need:

1. Execute Groovy expression that is contained in java.lang.String
2. Get result of the expression as an Object
3. Determine type of the resulting object

Is it possible? Also, if I won't use dynamic features of Groovy, will I be able to determine type of the expression "statically", i.e. in compile-time without executing expression itself.

Thanks

Comment: Combine http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060427/groovy-grails-how-to-determine-a-data-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple and easy way is to use the [Eval class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html). Evaluates the specified String expression and returns the result. The type result of the expression is `Object`.

```
def object = Eval.me('1 + 1')
```

You can get the class of an object with the `getClass()` method or simply:

```
assert object.class == Integer
```

In this example, is not possible determine the static type checking at compilation time.

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
void test() {
    Integer object = Eval.me('1 + 1')
    assert object.class == Integer
}

[Static type checking] - Cannot assign value of type java.lang.Object to variable of type java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: You could declare `Object object = Eval.me( '1+1' )` and I believe it would work?  But I guess that would be at Runtime which is your point ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's works, but we don't know the type at compilation time.

Comment: True.  Not sure if the type is stored in the `ASTNode` metaData (if you pass the string to `AstBuilder` for example)