# Determine variable type

Tags: java, groovy

How can I determine type of `Groovy` variable using `Java`?
For example we have the next `Groovy` code:

```
a = new Integer(4);
b = a + 1;
a = "b = " + b;
```

How can we programatically analyze it and determine that type of `a` variable at `b = a + 1;` line is `java.lang.Integer`?

As `a` is dynamic variable we can't get its type from `Groovy AST`, because `AST` doesn't contain such info.

1. update: added more details
2. update: clarified question

Comment: a.getClass() would do it.

More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060427/groovy-grails-how-to-determine-a-data-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible using `StaticTypeCheckingVisitor`. [In order to see more details, please, follow this link](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Determine-type-of-Groovy-variable-using-Java-td5712228.html)

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use `instanceof` to determine a type of an object

Comment: Thanks for response, `instanceof` will help to determine a type of an object inside code, but I need to determine a type outside of code - i.e. some kind of code analyzer with type inferencing.