# Example for type inference in groovy

Tags: groovy, type-inference

Can anyone show me a simple example for type inference in groovy and the advantage of it?
I read already many articles and a book about groovy but couln't find a simple example for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this simple enough to apprehend?

```
def doSomething(a, b){
   a + b
}

//Type inferred to String
assert "HelloWorld" == doSomething('Hello','World')
assert "String" == doSomething('Hello','World').class.simpleName

//Type inferred to Integer
assert 5 == doSomething(2,3)
assert "Integer" == doSomething(2,3).class.simpleName

//Type inferred to BigDecimal
assert 6.5 == doSomething(2.7,3.8)
assert "BigDecimal" == doSomething(2.7,3.8).class.simpleName

//Type inferred to Double
assert 6.5d == doSomething(2.7d,3.8d)
assert "Double" == doSomething(2.7d,3.8d).class.simpleName
```

Comment: I believe this is just a runtime reflection. Type inference is a compile-time feature.

Comment: @Natix You need to understand how [Dynamic Method Dispatch](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_multi_methods) works in Groovy before down voting the answer. :-) Type is inferred during runtime. That is the specialty of Groovy which makes it dynamic and puts it above others. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I [wrote an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910863/groovy-determining-the-expected-return-type-dynamically-from-within-method/17003053#17003053) sometime ago with an example. Check that the `animal()` method return type is `def`, and it returns two objects of different types. It infers the common supertype of both.

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Cases {
  static main(args) {
    def bat = new Cases().animal "bat"

    assert bat.name == "bat" // Works fine

    assert bat.favoriteBloodType == "A+" // Won't compile with error 
                                         // "No such property: favoriteBloodType
                                         // for class: Animal"
  }

  def animal(animalType) {
    if (animalType == "bat") {
      new Bat(name: "bat", favoriteBloodType: "A+")
    } else {
      new Chicken(name: "chicken", weight: 3.4)
    }
  }
}

abstract class Animal {
  String name
}

class Bat extends Animal {
  String favoriteBloodType
}

class Chicken extends Animal {
  BigDecimal weight
}
```