# Jenkins pipeline: return value of build step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In this integration pipeline in Jenkins, I am triggering different builds in parallel using [the build step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/), as follows:

```
stage('trigger all builds')
{
  parallel
  {
    stage('componentA')
    {
      steps
      {
        script 
        {
          def myjob=build job: 'componentA', propagate: true, wait: true
        }
      }
    }
    stage('componentB')
    {
      steps 
      {
        script
        {
          def myjob=build job: 'componentB', propagate: true, wait: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to access the return value of the `build` step, so that I can know in my Groovy scripts what job name, number was triggered.

I have found in the examples that the object returned has getters like `getProjectName()` or `getNumber()` that I can use for this.

But how do I know the exact class of the returned object and the list of methods I can call on it? This seems to be missing from the [Pipeline documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/). I am asking for this case in particular, but generally speaking, how can I know the class of the returned object and its documentation?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The step documentation is generated based on some files that are bundled with the plugin, which sometimes isn't enough. One easy way would be to just print out the `class` of the result object by calling [`getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--):

```groovy
def myjob=build job: 'componentB', propagate: true, wait: true
echo "${myjob.getClass()}"
```

This output would tell you that the result (in this case) is a `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper` which has [published Javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html).

For other cases, I usually have to dive into the Jenkins source code. Here is my general strategy:

- Figure out which plugin the step comes from either by the step documentation, [jenkins.io steps reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-%20build%20a%20job), or just searching the internet
- From the [plugin site](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-build-step), go to the [source code repository](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin)
- Search for the String literal of the step name, and find the step type that returns it. In this case, it looks to be coming from [the `BuildTriggerStep` class, which `extends AbstractStepImpl`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/c82f48fb270ec96a3f6a84d6ad61ae214f572fe4/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStep.java#L124)

  ```java
  @Override
  public String getFunctionName() {
      return "build";
  }
  ```
- Look at [the nested `DescriptorImpl` to see what execution class is returned](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/c82f48fb270ec96a3f6a84d6ad61ae214f572fe4/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStep.java#L85-L87)

  ```java
  public DescriptorImpl() {
      super(BuildTriggerStepExecution.class);
  }
  ```
- Go to [`BuildTriggerStepExecution` and look at the execution body in the `start()` method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/c82f48fb270ec96a3f6a84d6ad61ae214f572fe4/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStepExecution.java#L60-L148)
- Reading over the [workflow step README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-step-api-plugin/blob/master/README.md#creating-an-asynchronous-step) shows that something should call `context.onSuccess(value)` to return a result. There is one place in that file, but that is only on the "no-wait" case, which always returns immediately and is `null` ([source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/c82f48fb270ec96a3f6a84d6ad61ae214f572fe4/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStepExecution.java#L142-L147)).

  ```java
  if (step.getWait()) {
      return false;
  } else {
      getContext().onSuccess(null);
      return true;
  }
  ```
- Ok, so it isn't completing in the step execution, so it must be somwhere else. We can also search the repository for `onSuccess` and see what else might trigger it from this plugin. [We find that a `RunListener` implementation handles setting the result asynchronously for the step execution if it has been configured that way:](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/c82f48fb270ec96a3f6a84d6ad61ae214f572fe4/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerListener.java#L44-L56)

  ```java
  for (BuildTriggerAction.Trigger trigger : BuildTriggerAction.triggersFor(run)) {
      LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "completing {0} for {1}", new Object[] {run, trigger.context});
      if (!trigger.propagate || run.getResult() == Result.SUCCESS) {
          if (trigger.interruption == null) {
              trigger.context.onSuccess(new RunWrapper(run, false));
          } else {
              trigger.context.onFailure(trigger.interruption);
          }
      } else {
          trigger.context.onFailure(new AbortException(run.getFullDisplayName() + " completed with status " + run.getResult() + " (propagate: false to ignore)"));
      }
  }
  run.getActions().removeAll(run.getActions(BuildTriggerAction.class));
  ```
- The `trigger.context.onSuccess(new RunWrapper(run, false));` is where the `RunWrapper` result comes from

Comment: is there a possibility for the triggered job to return a return code that indicates whether it was successfully finished or whether it has failed? If yes, please give an example

Comment: @anarchipur Please [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73995884/4850949), which gives such an example.

Answer (score 5):

The result of the downstream job is given in the `result` attribute of the returned object.

I recommend to use `propagate: false` to get control of how the result of the downstream job affects the current build.

Example:

```
pipeline{
    [...]
    stages {
        stage('Dummy') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello world #1"
            }
        }
        stage('Fails') {
            steps {
                script {
                    downstream = build job: 'Pipeline Test 2', propagate: false
                    if (downstream.result != 'SUCCESS') {
                        unstable(message: "Downstream job result is ${downstream.result}")
                    }
                }
 
            }
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

In this example, the current build is set to UNSTABLE whenever the downstream build has not been successful.

The result can be: SUCCESS, FAILURE, UNSTABLE, or ABORTED.

For your other question see [Is there a built-in function to print all the current properties and values of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/192109/4850949) and [Groovy / grails how to determine a data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2060427/4850949)

Answer (score 0):

I got the class path from build log:
*13:20:52  org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper@5fe8d20f*

and then I found the doc from https://javadoc.jenkins.io/, you can get all you need from this page
link: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html