# Jenkins pipeline execute job and get status

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, dsl

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'master' }
stages {
    stage('test') {
        steps {
            script {
                def job_exec_details = build job: 'build_job'
                
                if (job_exec_details.status == 'Failed') {
                   echo "JOB FAILED"
                }
            }    
        }
    }
```

}
}

**I have a pipeline that executing build job, how can I get Job result in jenkins pipeline ?**

Comment: See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103359/jenkins-pipeline-return-value-of-build-step) for further information

Comment: @NoamHelmer that question and this question too different question.

Comment: @DashrathMundkar Why? it is a detailed explanation of how to extract all the needed information from the object returned by the build step, which is exactly what he needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `getResult()` and status should be `FAILURE` not `Failed`.

so your whole code should be like this

```
  pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def job_exec_details = build job: 'build_job', propagate: false, wait: true // Here wait: true means current running job will wait for build_job to finish.
                    
                    if (job_exec_details.getResult() == 'FAILURE') {
                       echo "JOB FAILED"
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is a second way of getting results:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
      stage('test') {
        steps {
          build(job: 'build_job', propagate: true, wait: true)
        }
      }
    }
    post { 
      success { 
        echo 'Job result is success'
      }
      failure { 
        echo 'Job result is failure'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about 'build' step [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)