# Can the build method in groovy return the build ID and build status?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Can the build method in groovy return the build ID and build status when the job has completed ?
For example if I write a code like this:

```
Object buildData = build(job: 'xyz', parameters: [....])
```

What all things can I fetch from `buildData` Object ?
Currently I have a need to fetch build ID and build status

Comment: Here is an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/51105617/10721630

Answer (score 0):

The build method returns an Object of Class `RunWrapper`: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper`

All the methods that can be used using this object are present here: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).