# How to get the information of downstream job which got triggered by upstream visa scripted pipeline

Tags: api, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to get the information of downstream job which got triggered by upstream

for example A - parent job which has triggered B C and D as downstream job,

I wanted to get the info (job name and build number) of  B C and D which triggered by A

Comment: Could you post your script where you trigger the downstream jobs to begin with ?

Comment: From Job D you can get the information of the entire upstream chain, but from job A you can get information only for the direct downstream job (B)

Comment: @NoamHelmer, could you please help with the "how to get information of direct downstream job (B) "

Comment: @helen Check out [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103359/jenkins-pipeline-return-value-of-build-step) it explains the return output of the `build` step.