# How to get Jenkins build status without running build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How can I get the status of already completed builds?

The code below starts the build, but I just need to know the build status by name.
I need to find out the names of the failed builds in order to send the data in one message to the mail.

```
Map buildResults = [:]

Boolean failedJobs = false

void nofify_email(Map results) {
    echo "TEST SIMULATE notify: ${results.toString()}"
}

Boolean buildJob(String jobName, Map results) {

    def jobBuild = **build job: jobName**, propagate: false

    def jobResult = jobBuild.getResult()

    echo "Build of '${jobName}' returned result: ${jobResult}"

    results[jobName] = jobResult

    return jobResult == 'SUCCESS'
}
```

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {

        stage('Parallel Builds') {

            steps {

                parallel(

                        "testJob1": {
                            script {
                                if (!buildJob('testJob1', buildResults)) {
                                    failedJobs = true
                                }
                            }
                        },
                )
            }
        }
```

I couldn't find anything to replace **build job**

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73995884/1655780). "build" is the step to build a job by name.

build returns an object with a ".result"  property that you can interrogate directly... assuming you let the job complete (wait: false).