# Need help using same method for multiple pipelines

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I have a following method to give available drive for windows in Shared library
getAvailableDrive.groovy

```
#!groovy

def call(){
    def drivesInfo=bat(script: '@echo off && fsutil fsinfo drives', returnStdout: true).trim()
    usedDrives=drivesInfo.substring(8).tokenize(" ")
    def drivesList=[]
    for(alpha = 'A'; alpha <= 'Z'; ++alpha){
        drivesList.add("${alpha}:\\")
    }
    usedDrives.each{
        if(drivesList.contains("${it}"))
            drivesList.remove("${it}")
    }
    if(0==usedDrives.size())
        throw new Exception("No unused Drive/s Found!")
    return drivesList[0].take(2)
}
```

We have single windows node with executers 10, When multiple pipelines run at a same time, sometimes getAvailableDrive() gives same value to different pipeline. I wanted pipelines to use getAvailableDrive() in sequence.  Any input on resolving this issue would be very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option might be to "promote" `getAvailableDrive.groovy` to a pipeline and move it to a separate Jenkins Job. This allows you to set `pipeline { options { disableConcurrentBuilds() } ... }` and only allow one running at a time.

To trigger the new Job, from another running pipeline, you can use the [build(...)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) command. This does require you to save the (return) information external to the pipeline **OR** *somewhat* more "dirty": use the Jobs's Build/Run description via the [return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51103359/jenkins-pipeline-return-value-of-build-step) of the `build(...)` command (an [RunWrapper](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html) Object). You can set the new Job's Build/Run Description via `currentBuild.description = '...'`

I am unfamiliar with the reason why you need the specific drives; but maybe another storage solution (a Repo (Nexus/Artifactory) or something like S3) would serve you better in the long run? If you need the isolation; maybe combine it with dynamic agents via [Docker](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) or Kubernetes